# Incorrect Base64 decoding for some examples with C

Tags: c, gcc, base64

Hello and happy new year,

I wondered if you clever people could help me please. 
I am not getting the correct output from decoding the following:

```
CChcAAjpqs2/SsTt1uu4bw==
```

I am using the following:

base64.c/h from here
http://opensource.apple.com/source/ChatServer/ChatServer-263/jabberd2/util/base64.c
And I have tried one or two others with the same result.
My compiler is:
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

And here is my simple main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "base64.h"

int main(void)
{
    char* buf = 0;
    int   buflen = 0;
    buf = b64_decode("CChcAAjpqs2/SsTt1uu4bw==");
    if (buf)
    {
        buflen = (int)strlen(buf);
        printf("buf=%s\nbuflen=%d\n",buf,buflen);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It produces a result of:

```
buf(\
buflen=3
```

Which I wasn't expecting. I can successfully decode other examples, for example

```
HLJjwtxaMw+ZKPDEOqaf7g==
```

So I know the code isn't completely broken/wrong. Finally I also found a fantastic way of testing from my terminal and that results in an array of char longer than 3 and looks about right.

```
echo `echo CChcAAjpqs2/SsTt1uu4bw== | python -m base64 -d`
```

Any advice for a fairly novice programmer would genuinely be appreciated. Thank you.

Barry

Comment: `(base64 -d | xxd) <<< "CChcAAjpqs2/SsTt1uu4bw=="` works nicely too. No need for python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buflen = (int)strlen(buf);
```

`buf` is not null delimited string, `strlen` will not work. 
look at `ap_base64decode_len()`, that seem to return the decoded buf length.

```
printf("buf=%s\nbuflen=%d\n",buf,buflen);
```

same here, `%s` will not work. you are treating the decoded buf like a string.
print byte by byte using `%d` (to get the ascii values) or as Hex.

try this and you will see what is going on,

```
char* buf = 0;
int   buflen = 0;
buflen = ap_base64decode_len("CChcAAjpqs2/SsTt1uu4bw==");
buf = b64_decode("CChcAAjpqs2/SsTt1uu4bw==");
printf("buflen=%d\n",buflen);
int i;
for(i=0; i < buflen; i++)
{
    printf("%d,", (unsigned char) buf[i]);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much dpp.

Answer (score 1):

Your decoded string contains control characters. The result is in hex:

```
08 28 5c 00 08 e9 aa cd bf 4a c4 ed d6 eb b8 6f
```

`08` in ASCII is a backspace, which is why your `=` after `buf` in the output is missing. `28 5c` is `(\` and `00` is `\0` marking the end of the string, thus there is no more output after that.

You cannot output every decoded string in readable characters. You would have to replace them prior to output with some escape sequence or something. I actually don't know whether there is a standard library function for that. Especially the `\0` character might give you trouble with some other functions, too.